# CMD misinterpret command in script file of AutoHotKey

Tags: cmd, autohotkey

I am new in AutoHotKey and just trying to figure out how everything works. I created script that suppose to return the line inside parenthesis.

```
::.whole:: 
(
select user , select_priv , insert_priv from mysql.user;
)
```

It works fine in txt files, in chrome text fields and etc. but when i use it in windows command prompt i get this output:

```
select user , select_priv, insert_priv from mysql.user;.android
```

".android" appears only when i hit tab, but works as predicted when use enter or space. Where is this ".android" coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ".android" appears only when i hit tab, but works as predicted when
>   use enter or space. Where is this ".android" coming from?

Tab triggers autocompletion, .android is a folder in your current work directory (probably your user home directory?), the first in lexicographic order. Test this: On an empty comman prompt, press tab. .android will be proposed. If you keep pressing tab you can cycle through the folders and files in the current directory. It has nothing to do with your script.

The reason it does this is that ";" is seperating commands, so if you press tab after ";", it will do the same thing as if you pressed tab in an empty prompt.

Comment: I forgot about that kind of behavior in cmd, so you were right about auto-completion.